# LaunchScreen не загружает изображение в ImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, imageview, изображения, launchimage

У меня есть `Assets.xcassets`, в котором 2 изображения под названиями "`iTunesArtWork@1`" и "`google-small`". Оба формата `.png` . Во `ViewController`'e `LaunchScreen`'a у меня только квадратный `imageView` поцентру. Если у `imageView` в `Attributes Inspector` поставить любое из этих двух изображений, то `Storyboard` в обоих случаях будет всё отображать. Но если запустить на симуляторе, то "`google-small`" будет отображаться, а "`iTunesArtWork@1`" - нет.

Для ясности, вот ссылка на `GitHub`: https://github.com/megas781/Civilia_Simulator

**Ремарка**: проект разрабатывался на Xcode 8.3.3. Может в Xcode 9 такого бага (если это баг) нет.

P.S

Я думал, это какой-нибудь краш изображения, и пересоздал его в `Sketch`. То есть, абсолютно свежий `image`, но всё четно.

В Assets.xcassets все атрибуты абсолютно одинаковые, что у "`google-small`", что у "`iTunesArtWork@1`"

Answer (score 0):

вариант 1: вы поставили картинки не на х2 размер потому может не отображать на всех девайсах.

вариант 2: уберите @1 в названии картинки возможно при компиляции определяет как картинку для х1 а не универсальную (х2)

Ну и сториборд не всегда правильно показывает, у меня было такое что в сторибрде есть картинка а на девайсе пропадает, минут 20 бился не мог понять что происходит. А оказалось что в инспекторе не была прописана картинка( хотя сториборд исправно ее отображал)